# How to use axios without firing the 400 (Bad Request) message to the console

Tags: ruby, reactjs

I use axios to implement api with ruby ​​on rails
File apiCaller.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from './../constants/config';

export default function callApi(endpoind, method = 'GET', body) {
  return axios({
    method: method,
    url: API_URL + endpoind,
    data: body,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})}
```

File action.js

```
import * as types from './../constants/index';
import apiCaller from './../api/apiCaller';

export const atcPostContact = (contact) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return apiCaller('contacts', 'POST', contact)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch((postContact(res.data)));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error)
    })
}}
```

When I call the apiCaller function, if I enter the full parameters, there is no message that console => is correct.

But when I entered the wrong api and returned an error message, there was a message
 400 (Bad Request) in console on browser

Can you help me? Many thanks

Error picture as below

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this console message?

Comment: Because it shows a red error message on the console of the web, I don't want to

Comment: remove the `console.log('error', error)` line

Comment: Yes but why remove it, is it for your sake or your users's sake? It's standard for errored requests to be printed in the console.

Comment: I think when we have a product, there should be no error messages or warnings in the console

Comment: remove the console.log ('error', error) is not a solution

Comment: @sinafarhadi `console.log` isn't an error log, but `console.error` is.

Comment: ok; try console.error(error)

Answer (score 0):

This is the browser logging network errors to the console, not your code. You can turn it off... for yourself, if you like.

1. Press the little cog on the upper-right corner of console.
2. Either select the "hide network" checkbox, or deselect "Errors" from the dropdown.

[image]